# Get all roles for a specific user who is not logged (not current user)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am trying to write a basic users admin page in ASP.NET Identity 2 and I want to get the roles for a user. However, it is not the current user and I have only found how to get the roles for a current user (User.Identity).

I am trying to take a given user by Id which I pass (which is their id from ASPNetUsers) and get back which roles they have (which in the database is the join of Roles with ASPNetUserRoles but passing back only the Roles table)

I don't see a way to join to this table.

My psuedo code that doesn't work is something like:

```
    var myRoles = await db.Roles.Where(s => s.Users.First(u => u.UserId == id)).ToListAsync();
```

Does anyone know what to write a query given a userid to get all the roles assigned to it?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this using the code:

```
List<IdentityUserRole> myRoles =db.Users.Where(s => s.Id == id).FirstOrDefault().Roles.ToList();
```

The part that is confusing to me is that it doesn't return a Role but IdentityUserRole.

However, I was able to use the following code:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Roles(string id)
    {

        List<IdentityRole> allroles = db.Roles.ToList();


        var userrolemodel = new UserRoleViewModel()
        {
            AlllRoles = allroles,

            Id = id
        };
        return View(userrolemodel);

    }
```

and then

```
foreach (var org in Model.AlllRoles)
{
    var ischecked = Model.AlllRoles.First(s => s.Id == org.Id).Users.Any(s => s.UserId == Model.Id);
    <input type="checkbox" value="@org.Name" checked="@ischecked" name="orgs"/>
    @org.Name
    <br/>
}
```

Not incredibly efficient but straight forward enough for easy reading.